# Karabiner Elements requests Input Monitoring permission, even though it's already granted

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to set up Karabiner Elements 14.5.0 on a Mac Mini running macOS Monterey 12.4.

After installation, when I open the app, it requests Input Monitoring permission.  I have attempted to grant it in the directed location in System Preferences, namely Security & Privacy > Privacy > Input Monitoring, and checking karabiner_grabber and karabiner_observer.  However, the app does not work as expected after doing so and then closing the prompt window.  Reopening the app produces the same prompt. See screenshot.

[image: Windows showing request for permissions and same permissions already granted]

How can I get a working instance of Karabiner Elements on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Once you meet the permission issue, I suggest resetting it by `tccutil` and granting again.
Here is an example of how to reset Karabiner Elements.

```shell
tccutil reset All org.pqrs.Karabiner-Elements.Preferences
```

Comment: I have run the above command, with the success message: `Successfully reset All approval status for org.pqrs.Karabiner-Elements.Preferences`. This did not solve my issue.  I observe no change in the behavior above.

Comment: I realize karabiner uses many helper bins and I don't know how to find their bundle_id. You may try to reset **ALL** the privacy database by `tccutil reset All` and grant them again to see if helps.